# access to variable within inner class in java

Tags: java, variables, event-handling, inner-classes, jlabel

I'm trying to create an array of JLabels, all of them should go invisible when clicked. The problem comes when trying to set up the mouse listener through an inner class that needs access to the iteration variable of the loop used to declare the labels. Code is self-explanatory:

```
    for(int i=1; i<label.length; i++) {
       label[i] = new JLabel("label " + i);
       label[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
             label[i].setVisible(false);   // compilation error here
          }
       });
       cpane.add(label[i]);
    }
```

I thought that I could overcome this by the use of `this` or maybe `super` instead of the call of `label[i]` within the inner method but I haven't been able to figure it out.

The compilation error is: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`

I'm sure that the answer must be something really silly I haven't thought of or maybe I'm making some small mistake.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error is: `local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`

Comment: @omtinez: then perhaps you should declare the variable as `final`, no? (have a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045130/constructors-in-inner-classes-implementing-interfaces), also)

Comment: @Matt Ball, It isn't a good idea to have the iterator variable `final`.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425826/variable-is-accessed-within-inner-class-needs-to-be-declared-final

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your local variable must be `final` to be accessed from the inner (and anonymous) class.

You can change your code for something like this :

```
for (int i = 1; i < label.length; i++) {
    final JLabel currentLabel =new JLabel("label " + i); 
    currentLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            currentLabel.setVisible(false);   // No more compilation error here
        }
    });
    label[i] = currentLabel;
}
```

From the JLS :

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared `final`.
>
> Any local variable used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned [(§16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) before the body of the inner class.

---

**Resources :**

- [JLS - Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

Comment: it would be helpful to be able to use the iterator variable for other methods that I considered irrelevant to the question as well

Comment: @Colin Hebert Your "resources" link seems linking other document than section 8.1.3

Comment: @trante, thanks it was referring to a previous JLS, hosted by sun. It's now up to date.

Comment: **Upd**: starting in Java SE 8, a local class can access local variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or effectively final. See [accessing members of an enclosing class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class)

Answer (score 4):

If you're having a problem accessing `i`, make another variable outside the scope of your inner-class (e.g. before `label[i].addMouseListener(...)`):

```
for(int i=1; i<label.length; i++) {
   label[i] = new JLabel("label " + i);

   final int localI = i;
   label[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
         label[localI].setVisible(false);
      }
   });
   cpane.add(label[i]);
}
```

Comment: maybe not the most elegant solution, but I think that this should do the job

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `getSource` in your program. After this you can access your component with the help of `typecasting`. it will reduce extra lines of code,
your code will look like this

```
for (int i = 1; i < label.length; i++) { 
   currentLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(e) {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
         JLabel label = (JLabel) me.getSource();
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `label` is not specified as `final`.

Declare the array of labels as:

`final JLabel[] label;`

instead of:

`JLabel[] label;`

Your `MouseAdapter` is not an inner class; it's an *anonymous* class. Anonymous classes can only refer to `final` variables of their enclosing code.

Comment: Actually, it's an *anonymous inner class*, anonymous meaning it doesn't have an explicit name, and inner meaning it's contained in another class.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inner classes may only access variables of the enclosing method that are `final`.