# Local variable is accessed from within inner class

Tags: java, android, string, final

I have check out answers like thees [Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425826/variable-is-accessed-within-inner-class-needs-to-be-declared-final) but it does not address what I am after

I have an on click listener and here is the code

`mUsername` is a EditText that is already defined same with the button

```
mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            username = username.trim();
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);// get compile error here 
                            startActivity(intent);
                   }
          }
});
```

The error says to set `String username = mUsername.getText().toString();` to final but then I can't redefine username with the trim? I don't know why it can be used in the logInInBackround as a parameter but not in the method?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trim it directly:

```
String username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
```

This saves you the intermediate local variable store.

Comment: true, lets just say I didn't want to do that, for other case? how could that be done?

Comment: @iqueqiorio You could use multiple local variables.

Comment: so declare the second one like this `String usernameTrimmed;`

Comment: @iqueqiorio Yes, exactly. Or, you could trim it inside the inner class (not writing it back to `username` since it would be final)

Comment: so do the trim on this line `intent.putExtra("username", username);`

Comment: @iqueqiorio Yes, or you could always make a local variable inside the inner class.