# Local variable log defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm new to lambda and Java8. I'm facing following error.

> Local variable log defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
>   effectively final

```
public JavaRDD<String> modify(JavaRDD<String> filteredRdd) {

    filteredRdd.map(log -> {

        placeHolder.forEach(text -> {

            //error comes here
            log = log.replace(text, ",");

        });

        return log;

    });

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The message says exactly what the problem is: your variable *log* must be final (that is: carry the keyword final) or be effectively final (that is: you only assign a value to it *once* outside of the lambda). Otherwise, you can't use that variable within your lambda statement.

But of course, that conflicts with your usage of *log*. The point is: you can't write to something external from within the lambda ... so you have to step back and look for other ways for whatever you intend to do.

In that sense: just believe the compiler.

Beyond that, there is one **core** point to understand: you can **not** use a local variable that you can write to. Local variables are "copied" into the context of the lambda at runtime, and in order to achieve deterministic behavior, they can only be read, and should be **constants**.

If your use case is to *write* to some object, then it should be a field of your enclosing class for example!

So, long story short:

- **local** variables used (read) inside a lambda must act like a **constant**
- you can not **write** to local variables!
- or the other way round: if you need something to write to, you have to use a field of your surrounding class for example (or provide a call back method)

Answer (score 15):

The reason for this limitation is **the same as the reason for the Java language feature that *local variables* accessed from within (anonymous) inner classes must be (effectively) final**.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27558512/437506) by rgettman gets into the details of it. rgettman explains the limitations in clear detail and I link to that answer because the behavior of lambda expressions should be same as that of anonymous inner classes. Note that such limitation does not exist for class or instance variables, however. The main reason for this is slightly complicated and I couldn't explain it better than what Roedy Green does it [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/nestedclasses.html#ANONYMOUSVISIBILITY). Copying here only so it is at one place:

> The rule is anonymous inner classes may only access final local
>   variables of the enclosing method. Why? Because the inner class’s
>   methods may be invoked later, long after the method that spawned it
>   has terminated, e.g. by an AWT (Advanced Windowing Toolkit) event. The
>   local variables are long gone. The anonymous class then must work with
>   flash frozen copies of just the ones it needs squirreled away covertly
>   by the compiler in the anonymous inner class object. You might ask,
>   why do the local variables have to be final? Could not the compiler
>   just as well take a copy of non-final local variables, much the way it
>   does for a non-final parameters? If it did so, you would have two
>   copies of the variable. Each could change independently, much like
>   caller and callee’s copy of a parameter, however you would use the
>   same syntax to access either copy. This would be confusing. So Sun
>   insisted the local be final. This makes irrelevant that there are
>   actually two copies of it.
>
> The ability for an anonymous class to access the caller’s final local
>   variables is really just syntactic sugar for automatically passing in
>   some local variables as extra constructor parameters. The whole thing
>   smells to me of diluted eau de kludge.

Comment: I suggest using IDE feature to convert anonymous class snippets to lambda expressions to understand the interplay between the two (at least until you are comfortable with lambda expression scopes).

Answer (score 6):

In some use cases there can be a work around. The following code complains about the `startTime` variable not being effectively final:

```
List<Report> reportsBeforeTime = reports.stream()
                                        .filter(r->r.getTime().isAfter(startTime))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, just copy the value to a final variable before passing it to lambda:

```
final LocalTime finalStartTime = startTime;
    List<Report> reportsBeforeTime = reports.stream()
                                            .filter(r->r.getTime().isAfter(finalStartTime))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, If you need to change a local variable inside a lambda function, that won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Remember method inner classes can't modify any value from their surrounding method. Your second lambda expression in foreach is trying to access its surrounding method variable (log).

To solve this you can avoid using lambda in foreach and so a simple for each and replace all the values in log.

```
    filteredRdd.map(log -> {
        for (String text : placeHolder){
            log = log.replace(text,",");
        }
        return log;
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to create your own object wrapper, you can use `AtomicReference`, for example:

```
AtomicReference<String> data = new AtomicReference<>();

Test.lamdaTest(()-> {
    //data = ans.get(); <--- can't do this, so we do as below
    data.set("to change local variable"); 
});

return data.get();
```

Comment: This solution works perfect and fits into many cases as e.g. JOOQ TX lambda:
```
AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>();
jooq.transaction((Configuration tx) -> {
    ....
    result.set(...);
    ....
}
return result.get();
```

Comment: I'm not sure using AtomicReference for this gives the reader à clear idea of why it is being used. A MutableObject from apache commons or something similar would probably be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to encapsulate the code in an enclosing (inner class). You can define this:

```
    public abstract class ValueContext<T> {

    public T value;

    public abstract void run();
}
```

And then use it like this (example of a String value):

```
final ValueContext<String> context = new ValueContext<String>(myString) {

@Override
public void run() { 

// Your code here; lambda or other enclosing classes that want to work on myString,
// but use 'value' instead of 'myString'

        value = doSomethingWithMyString(value);

}};

context.run();

myString = context.value;
```