# Set a local variable value from inside a lambda

Tags: java, lambda, scope

I have the following code:

```
  public void visitStrAttribute(String attributeName, Consumer<String> attributeConsumer) {
    IntConsumer intConsumer;
    int stringByteArrayLength = 0;
    visitIntAttribute("", (IntValue) -> stringByteArrayLength = IntValue);
    attributeConsumer
        .accept(new String(readInputStream(stringByteArrayLength), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
```

I need to set `stringByteArrayLength` inside the lambda but an error message appears and it told me `Local variable stringByteArrayLength defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need an object, so that you can change the value of it's property, without having to modify the local variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local variable log defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402493/local-variable-log-defined-in-an-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-or-effectively-fi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives here:

- Create an class to  have this attribute, so the object from it will be final, but not  the instance  variables
- Make the variable class scope  (be careful with multithreading)

These solutions work, but maybe it's not the best option, so to have some inspiration see: [Lambdas: local variables need final, instance variables don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055392/lambdas-local-variables-need-final-instance-variables-dont)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make your variable a final array with one element, and modify the element inside it, like this:

```
final int[] stringByteArrayLength = {0};
visitIntAttribute("", (IntValue) -> stringByteArrayLength[0] = IntValue);
```

Although I don't consider it a best practice. I would rather return a new changed value rather than changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Create wrapper:

```
private static class Integerwrapper {
    private int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

and use as your int.

edit:

You can use int wrapper like: **AtomicInteger**