# How can code use an object inside a button?

Tags: java, swing, class, compiler-errors, jbutton

I have an issue. I want to use my object which is outside a button, and I get an error message:

```
Local variable es defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

```
File inputfile = new File("./input.txt");
testobject to = null;
try {
    Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(inputfile);
    String text1 = inputscan.nextLine();
    String text2 = inputscan.nextLine();
    to = new testobject(text1,text2);

    inputscan.close();
} catch (Exception e)  {
    System.err.println(e);
}

JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        to.setSomething("test");
    }
});
```

Obviously, I have a class with a constructor etc... but I have a problem that I cant reach my object inside the button.

Comment: You can implement the ActionListener interface on your `testobject`, or you can create a class that implement the ActionListener and that receive in input the `testobject` instance. Of course you still have the problem that your `tesobject` instance can be null.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38402625/1531124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the first method, maybe I did something worng but it didn't work.
The second method is working, but this create a new object in the button, so if I want to use outside a button, I need to set everything again. And in my program it is very complicated etc...

So the solution I created an Arraylist and I can use this inside and outside the button too.

```
ArrayList<testobject> list = new ArrayList<testobject>();
```

And after this I set the first (0) element to my data

```
list.add(new testobject(text1,text2));
```

And after this I can easily use easily the methods of the class

```
list.get(0).setSomething("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables that you want to use inside anonymous classes, like your `ActionListener` need to be final. You are initializing the variable with null and change it to the object created from the text input later.

You could instead create the object using a no args constructor and use setters to set the value in your `testobject`.

```
// Class names should start with a uppercase
testobject to = new testobject();
// Use try-with-resources to close them automatically.
try(Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(inputfile)){
    to.setText1(inputscan.nextLine());
    to.setText2(inputs can.neytLine());
 } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e)
 }
JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        to.setSomething("test");
    }
});
```

Or initialize the variable inside your `actionPerfromed` method. The downside is that you can't access the testobject outside of the method.

```
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         try(Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(inputfile)){
             testobject to = new testobject(inputscan.nextLine(), inputscan.nextLine());
             to.setSomething("test");
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e)
         }
     }
});
```