# How I add a stream into a loop, using filter to compare a global variable?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I'm practice algorithms and I'm trying to make a stream inside a loop where the length is equals to the size of another array. There I made 2 arrays: counts[] and cp[]

```
public static boolean getReturnOrigin(List<Character> list) {
        
    //list:['n', 's', 's', 'w', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'w', 'w', 'w']
            
    // counts: {n, s, e, w}
    int[] counts = {0,0,0,0};
    char [] cp = {'n', 's', 'e', 'w'};
        
    for(int x = 0; x<counts.length; x++) {
        counts[x] = (int) list.stream().
                filter(i -> i==cp[x])
                .count();
    }
        
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to store intengers in counts[] using a loop, adding a stream inside. In the stream I want to use filter to compare with each cp[x].

But I get an error in cp[x], with the message "local variable x defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

Anyone can help me to how can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local variable log defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402493/local-variable-log-defined-in-an-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-or-effectively-fi)

Comment: If you “practice algorithms” you should note that this is a very inefficient approach. Hiding the second loop in a Stream operation does not change the fact that you have two nested loops here. Compare with `for(Character c: list) { switch(c) { case 'n' -> counts[0]++; case 's' -> counts[1]++; case 'e' -> counts[2]++; case 'w' -> counts[3]++; } }` which does just a single loop. But your question looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) anyway, as your `return true;` hides the actual goal (which might have a better solution)

Answer (score 0):

just like the error message said, you are trying to pass a local variable into a lambda expression, which not allow if the variable in case that variable was not a final or effectively final.

you can try to fix it which this one

```
for(int x = 0; x<counts.length; x++) {
    final int finalValue = x;
    counts[x] = (int) list.stream().
            filter(i -> i==cp[finalValue])
            .count();
}
```

Comment: Or `final char cpx = cp[x];`

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I get an error in cp[x], with the message "local variable x defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" ..."*

The following is from the *[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/index.html)*.

*[8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)*,

> *"... Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be final or effectively final ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)), as specified in [§6.5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1). ..."*

> *"... Anyone can help me to how can I resolve this?"*

The advanced *[for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)* will produce *effectively-final* values, so iterate on *cp*.

```java
Character[] list = { 'n', 's', 's', 'w', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'w', 'w', 'w' };
int[] counts = {0,0,0,0};
char [] cp = {'n', 's', 'e', 'w'};
int i = 0;
for (char c : cp)
    counts[i++] = (int) Stream.of(list).filter(x -> x == c).count();
```

Output

```
[3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below code is helpful

```
            import java.util.Arrays;
            import java.util.List;

            public class Main {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    List<Character> charList = Arrays.asList('n', 's', 's', 'w', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'w', 'w', 'w');
                    
                    boolean result = getReturnOrigin(charList);
                    
                    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
                }

                public static boolean getReturnOrigin(List<Character> list) {

                    // list:['n', 's', 's', 'w', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'w', 'w', 'w']

                    // counts: {n, s, e, w}
                    int[] counts = {0, 0, 0, 0};
                    char[] cp = {'n', 's', 'e', 'w'};

                    for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
                        int finalX = x; // Create an effectively final copy of x
                        counts[x] = (int) list.stream()
                                .filter(i -> i == cp[finalX]) // Use the finalX copy here
                                .count();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
```

The error you are facing,
**"local variable x defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"**

is because you're trying to access the variable x inside the lambda expression of the filter method, but x is not effectively final within the loop. In Java, lambda expressions can only access local variables that are effectively final, which means they should not be modified after their initial assignment.

To work around this, you can create a copy of x that is effectively final and can be used within the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

> error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

this error is because you're trying to access the non-final variable `x` inside the lambda expression. In Java, only final or effectively final variables can be accessed in a lambda expression. Final variables are those declared with final modifier:

```
final int x2 = 0;
```

and effectively-final are those which dont have final modifier, but are assigned only once:

```
int x2 = 0; // not modified later on
```

You can fix this error by creating a final copy of `x` inside the loop, and use that in your lambda expression:

```
for(int x = 0; x<counts.length; x++) {
    final int finalX = x; //actually, final is not required 
                          //here, but makes it clear why the copy is made.
                          //also, final here prevents accidental modify of this variable if the code grows.
    counts[x] = (int) list.stream().
            filter(i -> i==cp[finalX])
            .count();
}
```

Another solution would be to use `IntStream.range` instead of for loop:

```
    IntStream.range(0, counts.length).forEach(x ->
            counts[x] = (int) list.stream().filter(i -> i == cp[x]).count()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `Map`:

```
    Map<Character,Integer> map = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                    Function.identity(), e -> 1, (a,b) -> a + b));
```