# What to do to solve this error of declaring "variable accessed from inner class" in the case of ListView setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I have this code-block that is supposed to show a dialog alert box asking for user input that I am storing in a string variable but I am getting a "variable accessed from inner class" error with the variable position and parent. What should I do? Not able to declare this as Final or Public either?

```
title.setOnItemClickListener(
    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(pdf1.this);
            builder.setTitle("Title");

            // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(pdf1.this);
            // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            builder.setView(input);

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                    String theitem = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Intent m = new Intent(pdf1.this, noteview.class);

                    m.putExtra("me", theitem);
                    m.putExtra("date", datestr);
                    startActivity(m);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I do not see a variable `adapter`. Is it only `position` causing an error?

Comment: variable parent sorry!!

Comment: Do you know what to do ?

Comment: Declare `parent` as `final`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27558512/2958086 for why

Comment: if i do that it shows cnnot resolve symbol parent

Comment: Inside the class, `final Foo myParent = parent;` Then use `myParent`?

Comment: yes even then it shows that ...i have also tried making the arrayadapter outside to public ..but still doesnt help!!

Comment: If `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` is final, you can create a final String value inside the first inner class and reference that inside of the second inner class.