# How to use global variable in onClick() method?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use a global variable in my onClick() method. I have an AsyncTask() that uses the variable (BTW, I am using Microsoft Translator API and apparently in order to use Translate.execute I **need** to use AsyncTask()). However, whenever I try to use it, an error pops up, saying:

```
Variable "[variable]" is accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final.
```

However, my program requires that I change the variable later on (I'm not done yet, but I'm sure I will need to change the variable), so I can't declare it as final. I read from [Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425826/variable-is-accessed-within-inner-class-needs-to-be-declared-final) that you should globalize the variable.

Apparently, according to [Global variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java), you need to use public and static. But here's where I run into a problem. I run into this error when I try to globalize the variable:

```
Modifier "public" not allowed here

Modifier "static" not allowed here
```

Is there any way I can use the variable in a different scope and change it whenever my button is pressed? My code is:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String X = "";



                class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<DownloadManager.Request, Void, String> {


                        try {        
                            translatedText = Translate.execute(X, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);

                            return translatedText;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                }
                new MyAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You don´t need to declare the variable static. Just declare it in your class and will be able to use it inside a anonymous inner class

Comment: Why don't you use X as a global variable? Declare it outside the `OnClickListener` method

Comment: @TOP Even though I move it outside of an OnClickListener method, it still gives me the "Modifier public and static not allowed here" errors.

Comment: I am not sure which variable you are talking about? is it X or translatedText?

Comment: @Raphau X. translatedText is just a variable I'm going to use later.

Comment: please edit your question to show the *complete* code exaple. The excerpt is too short and missleads to wrong answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public String X = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit); 
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<DownloadManager.Request, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(DownloadManager.Request... params) {
                    try {
                        translatedText = Translate.execute(X, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);

                        return translatedText;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return "";
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If I understood correctly it should be like that:
declare your

```
public String X = "";
```

in the outer class, outside of the onClick method.
Next you need to declare constructor and member for your MyAsyncTask

```
private String mTextToTranslate;
public MyAsyncTask(String x){
    mTextToTranslate = x;
}
```

and in the end use mTextToTranslate instead of X

Answer (score 0):

When you implement *onClickListener()* the way you are doing, in this case an anonymous inner class is implementing this interface and hence you cannot use a variable that is not *final* this way.

Your *AsyncTask* should be having a constructor and you should be passing this variable to that constructor and having it stored inside *AsyncTask*. Then you could go on further with your code without having this problem.