# Change Overrided Method to Single-Threaded

Tags: android, concurrency, synchronous, thread-synchronization, mediaprojectionmanager

How can I create an overrided method where the method is forced to be single-threaded (not async) when originally it was multi-threaded? Specifically I am trying to avoid a "dequeueOutputBuffer can't be used in async mode" error in [Grafika's ScreenRecordActivity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ScreenRecordActivity.java). "info" variable needs to be volatile not final.

```
@Override
public void onOutputBufferAvailable(...) {
    ...
    int outputBufIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);
```

Update #1
Stacktrack of error: [pastebin.com/sgJpyTnP](http://pastebin.com/sgJpyTnP)

```
E/MediaCodec: dequeueOutputBuffer can't be used in async mode
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.google.grafika, PID: 4469
                 java.lang.IllegalStateException
                     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
                     at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2632)
                     at com.android.grafika.ScreenRecordActivity$3$1.run(ScreenRecordActivity.java:283)
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                     at com.android.grafika.ScreenRecordActivity$3.onOutputBufferAvailable(ScreenRecordActivity.java:312)
                     at android.media.MediaCodec$EventHandler.handleCallback(MediaCodec.java:1682)
                     at android.media.MediaCodec$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaCodec.java:1629)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: would it be enough to execute this pice of code within the main thread ? Like getActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> { /*your code*/ });

Comment: @Mett Thanks, but still same error if I try: 
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {` 
`@Override` 
`public void run()` 
`{ encoderCallback = new MediaCodec.Callback() {` 
`...` 
`int outputBufIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);`

Comment: how about something like: `encoderCallback = new MediaCodec.Callback() {getActivity().runOnUiThread() -> { ... int outputBufIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, kTimeOutUs);}}` to ensure that whatever happens inside of the callback gets executed by the main Thread

Comment: @Mett Thanks again but that generates the error `"Variable 'info' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"` I can not declare info as final however because it needs to be volatile

Comment: @Mett I think I got it! To fix the error I created global variables for 'info' and other needed and copied the local variables to global upon use [post about the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425826/variable-is-accessed-within-inner-class-needs-to-be-declared-final). runOnUiThread() still causes the async error unfortunately. I made the small change of  `runOnUiThread()` to `Thread t1=new Thread` and it ran successfully!  Thanks SO much!! If you post this as an answer I will give you credit for solving it because it was your general idea.

Comment: Thanks but theres no need for that.
Im glad you found a solution :)

Comment: @Mett Yes, I appreciate your help a lot! In that case I am going to write up the answer and post it myself so that anyone with a similar issue will have a solution. I will make sure to acknowledge you in it; if there is an official way to acknowledge you let me know, otherwise I will just add a mention to you in the post.

Comment: @Mett Actually unfortunately I found out that the reason the error was not coming back when I created `new Thread` is I never _ran_ the thread. After running it I am getting the same error again. I am puzzled because it would seem the code is running not in async due to either being assigned a single thread or runOnUiThread() yet the error states otherwise. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: Could you please provide additional information such as the stacktrace you mentioned?

Comment: @Mett Thanks for looking into this more. I have provided the stacktrace as update #1, any other info I can provide?

Comment: Your Exception is kinda weird. It states `onOutputBufferAvailable(ScreenRecordActivity.java:312)` but ScreenRecordActivity only has 307 lines of code (as your github reference clearly shows). Does your local copy of the class differ from the one on github ?
And please add the stacktrace itself to your question.

Comment: @Mett Yes, my local copy included dequeueOutputBuffer and other methods not in the Google linked code for grabbing frames of screen captures. I discovered that Google advises writing the code much differently for synchronous mode as seen [in this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) under 'synchronous mode'. I will rewrite Grafika's code using code in the link to enable dequeueOutputBuffer. This hopefully will be the road to success and I will post if I can get it to work. Thanks again for working with me here, hopefully it will help others with similar cases