# Loose blocks of code

Tags: java

When I try running this piece of code, it prints "x y c g ". I know that x has priority over y because it is static and the constructor (c) prints before the method (g), but what exactly is the purpose of putting two lines in their own blocks, and what does this help achieve?

```
public class Sequence {
    Sequence() { System.out.print("c "); }
    { System.out.print("y ");}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sequence().go();
    }

    void go() { System.out.print("g "); }
    static { System.out.print("x "); }

}
```

Comment: `static` and instance initializer blocks is what they are called.

Comment: if you use proper indentation is easier to read, i don't get what is the problem if you know how is the initializer order. My english is not too good i can't understand this `but what exactly is the purpose of putting two lines in their own blocks, and what does this help achieve?`

Comment: Just because you can do something in a particular language doesn't mean you should. In this case, I'd imagine that you can implement some fancy design patters using such blocks of code, as the scoping logic and, as you pointed out, the order of execution would be unusual. Once again: I'd avoid such constructions. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: One advantage i see , is when you use anonymous classes, you don't have a constructor so if you want to do something in constructor you have to use instance initializer blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is closely related to this one, but not exactly a duplicate: [Why java Instance initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763550/why-java-instance-initializers)

When you first reference a class, it gets loaded and the static components get initialized in the static initializer. These blocks can be very useful, for setting up collections or loading native code.

An instance initializer is a bit of code that works similar to the static initializer except it operates on every instance before the constructor is invoked. It appears that there is no absolute need for this in Java since it can just be placed in the beginning of your constructor.