# Calling a method from another class - giving syntax error

Tags: java, oop

So I have a class that contains an arraylist and a 2nd class that defines an object. I have a 3rd class that instantiates the 1st once, and then instantiates the 2nd multiple times passing the instance of the 1st as a parameter- each time the 2nd is instantiated it should call the method of the 1st to add itself to the arraylist.

I'm getting an error calling the method of the 1st though saying syntax error on token misplaced contruct. My code is:

1st class:

```
public class One {

 private ArrayList<Two> list;

 One(){list = new ArrayList<Two>();}

 public void add(Two TwoInstance){
     list.add(TwoInstance);
 }
}
```

2nd class:

```
public class Two {

private String a = null;
private String b = null;
private long c = 0;
private int d = 0;
private int e = 0;
private One OneInstance;

Two(One oneInstance, String a, String b, long c, int d, int e)
{this.oneInstance = oneInstance; this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; this.d = d; this.e = e;} 

oneInstance.add(this);
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile, because it has at least one compiler error ´private One OneInstance´ vs ´this.oneInstance´ (upper vs. lower case)

Comment: Ah fair enough - had renamed the variables to try and make it more readable but obviously missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is because you have closed your constructor as mentioned here (check the curly braces)

```
Two(One oneInstance, String a, String b, long c, int d, int e)
{this.oneInstance = oneInstance; this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; this.d = d; this.e = e;}
```

and executable code outside block/method/constructors are not allowed , hence this line

```
oneInstance.add(this);
```

will throw an error. Move the above line in your constructor like this:

```
Two(One oneInstance, String a, String b, long c, int d, int e)
 {
     this.oneInstance = oneInstance; 
     this.a = a; 
     this.b = b;
     this.c = c; 
     this.d = d; 
     this.e = e;
     oneInstance.add(this);

 }
```

**Just an advice:** Better indentation can help you catch the syntax errors easily.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want your code to be in the constructor (e.g. if you are going to add more constructors and you want it to run for *all* constructors) or in a method, you have to surround it in curly braces:

```
{
   oneInstance.add(this);
}
```

But this feature, known as an [*instance initializer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763550/why-java-instance-initializers), is rarely used in Java. There is usually no need for it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was initially thinking would happen anyway but it's not actually required in my case. Thanks for the tip though - good to know!