# How to access an object of other class inside another class in android

Tags: android, sqlite

How would I access the sqlitedatabase object which is passed to startindexing method, inside my thread class?

```
public void startindexing (SQLiteDatabase db) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length-1; i++) {
                String cat = "O", ty;   
                values.put(NAME, filelist[i].getName());
                if (!filelist[i].isDirectory()) {
                                        ty = filelist[i].getName().substring(filelist[i].getName().lastIndexOf("."));
                    if (ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".mp3") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".wav") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".ogg") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".acc"))
                        cat = "A";
                    else if (ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".mp4") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".wmv") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".3gp") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".mkv") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".divx"))
                        cat = "V";
                    else if (ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".jpg") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".gif") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".png") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".bmp") || ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".webp"))
                        cat = "P";
                    else if (ty.equalsIgnoreCase(".txt"))
                        cat = "T";
                    values.put(TYPE,ty);
                } else { values.put(TYPE, "dir"); cat = "dir"; }
                values.put(CATEGORY, cat);
                values.put(PATH, filelist[i].getAbsolutePath());
                SQLiteDatabase db = ;
                db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        }
    }
}.start();
}
```

Comment: That was crazy-hard to read. Consider at least some minor refactoring, too.

Comment: Could you please share your another class where you pass the SQLiteDatabase's object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the parameter `final` then you will be able to directly access it inside your thread's `run()` method. See [How to pass parameters to anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107158/how-to-pass-parameters-to-anonymous-class)

```
public void startindexing (final SQLiteDatabase db)
```

Remove this line:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=;
```

Comment: i already tried that...wen i make the database object as final and run it, logcat says that my database object connection is not open...and i have already opened connection in another class from which i sent the object to this startidexing() method...plz help!

Comment: Make sure you aren't closing the DB connection somewhere else while your thread is running.