# Override method - Class variable

Tags: java

let me say first that I did try to Google this, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking  for. I understand I could use a setter method, but is there a way to access the fields directly?

```
List<String> token = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> lemma = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> pos   = new ArrayList<String>();

tt.setHandler(new TokenHandler<String>() {
   @Override
   public void token(final String token, final String pos, final String lemma) {
      this.token.add(token); // cannot be resolved or is not a field
      this.lemma.add(lemma); // cannot be resolved or is not a field
      this.pos.add(pos);     // cannot be resolved or is not a field
   }
});
```

Can you help me?!

Thanks!

Bob

Comment: delete `this` access just like `token`

Comment: In your function, this is the instance of TokenHandler. It hasn't those 3 variables.

Comment: This might help you to understand the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107158/how-to-pass-parameters-to-anonymous-class

Answer (score 4):

Using the keyword `this` in front of the variable, indicates that you want to access to instance fields. In this case the fields you would like to access, would belong to the anonymous class instance `new TokenHandler<String>() { //... }`. Since they are not declared inside the anonymous class, the compiler is not able to resolve them. That's why you are probably getting an error. 
Add the keyword `final` and access to the variables without the `this`-keyword:

```
final List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> lemmas = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> positions   = new ArrayList<String>();

tt.setHandler(new TokenHandler<String>() {
   @Override
   public void token(final String token, final String pos, final String lemma) {
      tokens.add(token); 
      lemmas.add(lemma); 
      positions.add(pos);
   }
});
```

For further information about why you need `final` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class) question.

**EDIT:**

Also, be careful with the ambigous names (parameter list vs. method variables).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Simon (and the others)! Anonymous class, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this.token` use `OuterClass.this.token` where `OuterClass` is the name of your class

Comment: The variables are not fields. So this would lead also to an error.

Comment: @Simon Indeed they are instance fields that's why he mentioned to use getter methods.

Comment: @Suhil You're right. The question is not clear about it. The code suggests that those variables are declared inside a method but at the same time he states he could use getters. If you edit your answer (add a whitespace or so), I can take back my downvote. :-)