# aria-disabled selenium code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wai-aria

I have a button that is enabled when I choose a value in a picker.

The html code states that aria-disabled="false" when i pick av value in the picker.

```
<button id="form:panel:j_idt188" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only btn btn-primary col-md-12 selectContext7" data-aft="selectLevel7" type="submit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:"form:panel:j_idt188",u:"form:kontekstvelger"});return false;" name="form:panel:j_idt188" role="button" aria-disabled="false"
```

How can I code that the selenium script should wait for the `aria-disabled="false"` to be false (It is true when I enter the page and before I have chosen a value in the picker.

From before I have this code to wait for elements:

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("nyid")));
```

But how can I write this code above to be waiting for aria-disabled to be false?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237129/webdriverwait-for-an-element-attribute-to-change/15237960#15237960

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cssSelector` to wait for element with specific id and attribute

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[id='nyid'][aria-disabled='false']")));
```

Comment: I did but get the message:
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for all conditions to be valid: presence of element located by: By.id: nyidvalue to be "false". Current value: "null"

Comment: and using firebug during test replay I get the value "true", I do not understand how the value can be "null", meybe the step before did not actually press the picker (the browser shows it does though)

Comment: @MagnusJensen You need to use `By.cssSelector`, not `By.id`. Just copy the code from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.and(
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("nyid")),
        ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.id("nyid"), "aria-disabled", "false")));
```

Comment: and if the above code times out in 10 seconds, the element was not found? right?