# How to write actionlistener in java

Tags: java, swing, awt

Below is my codes:

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("testcontent");
label1.setBounds(131, 57, 205, 74);

frame.getContentPane().add(label1);

JButton btn1 = new JButton("run");
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
});

btn1.setBounds(169, 206, 117, 25);
frame.getContentPane().add(btn1);
```

When I try to refer the label1 in the actionPerformed, eclipse cannot find the label1.
Any one could tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

`label1` is not available in the scope of the `ActionListener`. Either declare it as `final` or make it a class instance variable

```
final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("testcontent");
```

Comment: You're not using `final` as a design decision, you're using as a workaround- a completely unnecessary workaround, at that. It's poor programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around using `final` by doing what is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206542/771665) answer.

Basically, you pass in the label through an `init` method that you call immediately after creating an anonymous object. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private JLabel myLabel;
    private ActionListener init(JLabel var){
        myLabel = var;
        return this;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}.init(myVariable));
```

The reference `myLabel` is then accessible within `btn1`'s `actionPerformed`method.