# android: 3 different markers have same data onclick, inner class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, inner-classes

I have 3 markers in a map. I get marker data through a server and associate it through each marker. Due to data amount, I only get a subset of data for each marker (for development I have 3 markers, but there may be many more). So I associate an ID to each marker, and for the next activity, I get that ID and retrieve the complete data set for the next activity to be displayed.

Unfortunately all markers end up being associated with the **same ID**. What am I missing here?

Initially I was passing a `final` variable to the inner class in order to assign the ID. Finding this question: [How to pass parameters to anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107158/how-to-pass-parameters-to-anonymous-class) (kudos!) I introduced an initializer to the inner class, thinking the `final` attribute might have been the problem. But nope. Still getting the same ID on all markers.

```
   private class Getter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

            private Exception exception;
            protected static final String TAG = "Getter";

            protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    try {
                        //get JSON data from server
                        return json_objects.getJSONArray("objects");
                    } catch (JSONException jse) {
                        //more error handling
                    }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    this.exception = e;
                    return null;
                }
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray obj_arr) {
                try {
                    if (this.exception != null) {
                        //some error handling
                    } else if (obj_arr != null) {                    
                      for (int i = 0; i < obj_arr.length(); i++) {
                          JSONObject obj = obj_arr.getJSONObject(i);
                          create_marker(obj);
                      }

                    }
                } catch(JSONException jse) {
                  //error handling
                }
            }

            private void create_marker(JSONObject obj) {
                try {
                    JSONObject location = obj.getJSONObject("location");
                    double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
                    double lng = location.getDouble("lng");
                    String id = obj.getString("id");

                    LatLng pos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            pos).title(obj.getString("name")).                        
                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        String local_id;

                        public GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener init(String id) {
                            local_id = id;
                            return this;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("obj_id", local_id);
                            startActivity(i);
                            return false;
                        };
                    }.init(id));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   //error handling
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the `onMarkerClick` handler only can access the last local_id - is the constructor not constructing new instances for each anonymous listener?

Comment: Dam it. I realize now the listener is on the **map**, not the marker....I need a different approach. Posting solution when I've found one.

Comment: Ofcourse, It will take the last id only at every time. Because Listener may invoked at only once.

Comment: If you want to associate only Id (Or in future Object) with Clicked marker. Just implement `WeakHashMap<Marker, Object> markerMap` and put marker entry every time when you add it to map with Object, in your case it will ID.

Comment: yes @user370305 I found a link doing just that. :)