# Can you use a functor/functional programming to group a list in Java 7 (and count its elements per group)?

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava, apache-commons, functor

Can you group `List<TypeEnum> types = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TypeEnum.A, TypeEnum.B, TypeEnum.A));` into a `Map<TypeEnum, Integer> countPerType;`, using functors (e.g. [Google's Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained), [Apache's Commons Functor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-functor/)) **pre** Java 8?

I'm trying to get my head around functional programming, but am unsure if that sort of thing would actually be possible (as I'm not just mapping a collections value, but trying to aggregate)?

In imperative style, I would have done something like this:

```
public Map<TypeEnum, Integer> countByGroup(List<TypeEnum> types) {
    Map<TypeEnum, Integer> countedTypes = new HashMap<>();
    for(TypeEnum type : types) {
        if(countedTypes.containsKey(type)) {
            countedTypes.put(type, countedTypes.get(type) + 1);
        } else {
            countedTypes.put(type, 1);
        }
    }
    return countedTypes;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Relying on side effects seems somewhat inappropriate - or is that how it's done...?

```
Procedure<TypeEnum> count = new Procedure<TypeEnum>() {
public Map<TypeEnum, Integer> countPerType = null;

    @Override
    public void run(TypeEnum type) {
        if(countPerType.containsKey(type)) {
            countPerType.put(type, countPerType.get(type) + 1);
        } else {
            countPerType.put(type, 1);
        }
    }

    public Procedure<TypeEnum> init(Map<TypeEnum, Integer> countPerType) {
        this.countPerType = countPerType;
        return this;
    }
}.init(countPerType); // kudos http://stackoverflow.com/a/12206542/2018047
```

Comment: Using Guava, you want a simple [`Multiset`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), and more specifically its [`EnumMultiset`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EnumMultiset.html) implementation. `Multiset` is a data structure made to keep track of counted elements.

Comment: Java 8 is no magic, i.e. the Stream API consists of ordinary Java code using parameters of interface types. There is no reason why this shouldn’t work in pre-Java8 environments.

Comment: Yes, I know. As I stated, I'm trying to get my way around solving problems in a Java8ish style way using functional programming - without being able to use Java 8 itself yet... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Olivier Grégoire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180719/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514257/can-you-use-a-functor-functional-programming-to-group-a-list-in-java-7-and-coun#comment70241477_41514257) the correct answer:

> Using Guava, you want a simple [`Multiset`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), and more specifically its [`EnumMultiset`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EnumMultiset.html) implementation. `Multiset` is a data structure made to keep track of counted elements.

Given your `List<TypeEnum> types` you can create an `EnumMultiset` using [`create`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EnumMultiset.html#create-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
Multiset<TypeEnum> multiset = EnumMultiset.create(types);
```

And you can query for the count of an element in the `Multiset` using [`count`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EnumMultiset.html#count-java.lang.Object-):

```
multiset.count(TypeEnum.A); // 2
multiset.count(TypeEnum.B); // 1
```